# How to select different input type at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to do something like this in jQuery to select multiple input control so that I can bind the onchange event on all of them at the same time.

```
jQuery('div input[type=(text|select|radio|checkbox)]')
```

or is it something like this `jQuery('div input[type=*]')` ?

Comment: Do you want it to work for all types of inputs or just ones with specific types?

Comment: You may have a reason for this, but do you need to select with the div aswell, or would input alone be enough?

Comment: it needs to be a specific div element with a class I just used that for an example it goes like this jQuery('.wikiform .wizard .view :input').change(function() {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector:

```
jQuery("div :input").change(...
```

The [API](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) states that it *"Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements"*.

If you are looking to select a subset of input *types* within a container, you could use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), like this:

```
jQuery("div input[type=radio], input[type=text]").change(...
```

Comment: Out of interest, do you know if this also supports some of the newer types of input, like range and other HTML5 ones?

Comment: @Adam - I'm not sure. Good question though, I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: yeah that one will do but lefts say you have a selet box in a div for a jQuery plugin and the select box sometimes had an option "Please Choose" how would you programme it to descide not to take the first option of "Please Choose" the select boxes will vary on form to form for the jQuery plugin

Comment: @littleMan - presumably, the first `[please choose...]` option would have a null, dummy value, or no value at all, so it shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('div input').change(function() {
    //code
});
```

Comment: Beware that this will also select some submit buttons, although this might not be a problem for you

Comment: @Adam He did say all types of inputs.

Comment: True, and if that's what was intended, then fair enough. Just something to watch out for, as listening for the change event on a submit button might not be what he wants, perhaps?

Comment: true that. i need to put a :not() in there so how would it go. jQuery('wikiform .wizard .view :input:not(:button)').change